# How to set up my iOS storyboard to bounce like Instagram Stream?

Tags: ios, storyboard, instagram, bounce

I am building an app with a stream of social content and am trying to get the behavior of how instagram does it's stream in app.  So basically a top header that scrolls off the screen but bounces between that and the content.  I can make the top header scroll off the screen and I can make the view not bounce but I want to use Pull to refresh and that ends up going above the "faux" nav bar `UIView`.  I know that a normal Navbar will produce this but this one that scrolls off is a different story.

Currently I have a `UITableview` that has a `UIView` above the `UITableViewCell` and everything works great except the bounce happens above the `UIView`.  I figure I need to get the `UIView` above the `UITableView` however in the UITableViewController the storyboard won't allow me to place the `UIView` above the `UITableView`.

Any ideas???

Thanks

Comment: nobody huh??? I noticed the new Facebook 5 app also has this behavior on it's stream page. I'd really like to figure this app before I release my app to the wild.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I finally got this all to work so I thought I would post the Answer for everyone.

Basically I set a standard Navigation bar and then on `scrollViewDidScroll` I get the offset of the scrolling and change the frame based on that.  This seems to work perfectly, see below for my scrollViewDidScroll method.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {

    //Initializing the views and the new frame sizes.
    UINavigationBar *navbar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
    UIView *tableView = self.view;

    CGRect navBarFrame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
    CGRect tableFrame = self.view.frame;

    //changing the origin.y based on the current scroll view.
    //Adding +20 for the Status Bar since the offset is tied into that.
    navBarFrame.origin.y = MIN(0, (sender.contentOffset.y * -1)) +20;
    navbar.frame = navBarFrame;

    tableFrame.origin.y = MIN(0,MAX(-44,(sender.contentOffset.y * -1)));
    tableView.frame = tableFrame;

}
```

Also you will want to make your TableView 44px taller to compensate for the scrolling otherwise your frame will not be big enough.  I just did this in viewWillAppear and made the frame bigger.

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful but creating 1 problem, on sliding navigation bar is going up but leaving blank white space in place of navigation bar, and table is scrolling from that white space. How to solve this problem can you please help me.