# Instagram like Navbar + tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, user-interface, uikit, instagram

im trying to create a tableview like Instagram's main page, in particular im having problems recreating a UI with **ALL** these 3 features present

```
1)Top navigation bar hides when tableview is scrolled up 
2)Top navigation bar does not bounce when table is scrolled all the way down
3)Section content bounces on scrolling down when the top navigation bar is out
```

I have tried all forms of sectioned tableviews ive known, sectioned tableviews within sectioned tableviews and trying with scrollViewDidScroll but to no avail.

Comment: Found the answer here on this thread

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450959/how-to-set-up-my-ios-storyboard-to-bounce-like-instagram-stream][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450959/how-to-set-up-my-ios-storyboard-to-bounce-like-instagram-stream